# How can I change the layout manager of my JFrame after startup?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

**Background:** I'm working on a "GUI from Hell" program.

**Problem:** I need to change the layout manager of my JFrame from the constructor-set BorderLayout to FlowLayout.

**Purpose:** It's going to end up doing that many times really fast after a button is pressed, then end up on one layout manager or the other.

How should I accomplish this best? Here's some (working) code, if it helps at all:

```
if (goodVibes)
        {
            final Timer t = new Timer(100, null);
            ActionListener changeStyle = new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int count = 100;

                    // Insert layout manager switching code here

                    count--;
                    if (count <= 0)
                        t.stop();
                }
            };
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: You do understand that the way the Java Swing event threading mechanism works, you won't see any of these layout swaps? That all  you'll see is the last layout? What is the purpose of this code? What do you want the user to experience from this? Perhaps your best bet is to use CardLayout and a Swing Timer.

Comment: I assume the code is missing `t.addActionListener(changeStyle); t.start();`, because otherwise not much is going to happen.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Haha yes. This is one of four similar blocks of code, and I did remember those two lines in the first three blocks. Just hadn't tried to compile yet ;) edit: I'm actually using `t.addActionListener(flashColors);`, `t.setRepeats(true);`, and `t.start();`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's a "GUI from Hell" program. It doesn't have any practical use.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Right, I used CardLayout with Swing Timers as was suggested. Swing Timers were included with the original sample code, too...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not see your use of a timer. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you are going to have all different components? So put the components on a `JPanel` for each layout. Switch with `frame.setContentPane(panel);`.

Alternatively, use `java.awt.CardLayout` to switch between panels.

Comment: I vote for the CardLayout. Swapping couldn't be much easier than this.